# Yolov3: Sub-categories possible?

Tags: yolo

Just wondering if sub categories are at all possible within Yolov3? From what I understand Yolo9000 uses a wordnet hierarchy tree and therefore allows for sub-classes (aka Dog as a parent and specific breeds of dogs as sub-classes). However I cannot seem to find any information pertaining as to whether this is possible in yolov3? The overall goal/reasons is that I am looking to use a pretrained dataset and then possibly expand on certain objects to create sub-categories.